# CSS doesn't load when rendering HTML with express.js

Tags: css, express, ejs

I have 3 pages that use the same CSS file. The thing is 2 of the pages use the CSS correctly but the 3rd page acts as if there is no CSS at all. All of those 3 pages are sent thru express.js server.

I have my index.js (the server)

```
const express=require("express")
const app=express()

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}))

app.set("view engine","ejs")
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('home')
})

const tierListRouter=require('./routes/tierlist')
app.use("/tierlist",tierListRouter)
const summonersRouter=require('./routes/summoner')
app.use('/summoner',summonersRouter)
app.listen(3000)
```

I have my ejs files (the view engine I'm using) in "views" folder
and I have my style.css file and images in "public" folder
I'm rendering the ejs files in the routers
this is the router in which I'm trying to render the problematic file that uses no CSS

```
const express=require('express')
const router=express.Router()

router.get('/:name',async (req,res)=>{
    res.render("profile")
})

module.exports=router
```

and here is the head tag of the file

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>The PrideStalker Profile</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
```